# SOAP webservice in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap

I'm trying to connect with a SOAP Web-Service in iOS project using Xcode and Objective-C.

My problem is that all ways I have found is very primitive (like typing manual soap envelop and send it to HTTP Transporter (or something like) and then parse the response manually to extract the information).

I didn't find any professional way to do that.

Any ideas about libraries or better ways to do that?

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not have any native support to consume SOAP Web services. You need to make the clients to consume the services. [wsdl2objc](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) 
is very impressive tool to generate Objective-C code from a WSDL for calling SOAP services. 
You can refer to its [Usage instructions](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) for how to use the generated code from WSDL2ObjC